# Full Calendar not working correctly with Semantic UI

Tags: css, fullcalendar, semantic-ui

I work with Semantic-ui v2.2.11 and fullCalendar v3.4.0, my problem is that the dayClick event does not work with every day of the calendar in the months part,, if I remove the import css from semantic-ui the calendar works correctly.
I do not know much about css, but why does this happen?

[My JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/navastud/xg3L77es/19/)

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <head>

  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">

  <title>#{get 'title' /}</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="@{'/public/semantic-2.2.10/dist/semantic.css'}">
  <link rel="stylesheet"  href="@{'/public/fullcalendar 3.4.0/dist/fullcalendar.min.css'}">

  #{get 'moreStyles' /}

  <!-- Scripts -->
  <script src="@{'/public/jquery-3.2.1/dist/jquery.js'}"></script>
  <script src="@{'/public/moment/min/moment.min.js'}"></script>
  <script src="@{'/public/fullcalendar 3.4.0/dist/fullcalendar.min.js'}">   </script>
  <script src="@{'/public/fullcalendar 3.4.0/dist/locale/es.js'}"></script>
  <script src="@{'/public/semantic-2.2.10/dist/semantic.js'}"></script>

  #{get 'moreScripts' /}
  </head>
  <body>
  <div class="ui secondary pointing menu">
   <a class="active item">
    Home
   </a>
   <div class="right menu">
    <a class="ui item">
      Logout
    </a>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ui vertical left aligned segment">
   <div class="ui container">
    <h1>My calendar</h1>
    <p><a href="@{testCalendarSemantic}">Refresh</a></p>
    <div id="calendar"></div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

**JS**

```
$(function() {
    $('body #calendar').fullCalendar({
        navLinks: true,
        header:{
            left:'prev',
          center:'title',
          right:'next'
        },
        footer:{
            left:'today',
          center:'',
          right:'month,agendaDay,agendaWeek,list'
        },
        dayClick:function(){
            $(this).css('background-color','#cce6ff');
        },
        events:[
            {
                title:'first event',
                start: '2017-06-15 09:00',
                end:'2017-06-17 20:00',
            },
            {
                title:'first event',
                start: '2017-07-21 07:00',
                end:'2017-07-24 23:00',
            },
            {
                title:'first event',
                start: '2017-08-01 10:00',
                end:'2017-08-05 16:00',
            }
        ]
    });
});
```

[image]

Comment: well your JSfiddle includes semantic-ui CSS and seems to work fine. I can click on all the days, in all the views (apart from list, where you wouldn't expect it to work), and turn them blue. Can't reproduce your stated problem at all.

Comment: The problem is in the part of the months I can only click until the 26th day, I notice that in the mobile version it works correctly.
Attach an image to the post

Comment: I am not experiencing that problem while using the JSFiddle. I can click the whole of August 2017 quite happily (using Chrome desktop version 58.0.3029.110)

Comment: I tryed in Firefox 54.0 and Chrome 59.0.3071.115 and does not work the two final columns

Comment: you mean the final two _rows_ (as per your picture), not columns? Anyway I definitely don't have that problem in the JSFiddle. Maybe there's some difference between that and your own version? Or are you using the fiddle when you make this assertion? If I can't reproduce the problem I can't really help you, sorry. There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with it. I tried in IE11 and Firefox 54 as well, and no issues.

Comment: Thanks anyway, although my phone works correctly is as if something affected only those two rows, it may be that the browser development toolbar has to do? It's a guess only

Comment: I can't see why the dev tools would do it. They never affect the page content, unless you used them to explicitly modify something. I assume you don't get any errors in the dev console when this is happening?

Comment: not shows errors in the dev console

Comment: I tried on another pc and it works correctly, try disabling the add-ons of my browser but it still does not work

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve this problem by setting the css of the container:

```
height: auto
```

Comment: not worked, my computer has problem because in others computers worked correctly